# problemas com o radio button em um formulario html

Tags: html

Estou com um problema nos meus `Radio button`. Todos estão ficando selecionados no meu `html`.

Porque isso acontece? Tem alguma propriedade que seta isso?

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 4):

Adicione o `name` igual para os `inputs`.
Exemplo:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

Comment: resolvi o problema era o nome que está diferente no radio vlw galera pela ajuda :)

Comment: @EduardoLopes Considere selecionar a resposta que lhe ajudou e marcá-la como certa. Abraço.